# how to inject a promise into mdDialog AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-material

I want to take a variable of type `angular.IPromise<any>` and pass inject it into the controller of an `$mdDialog` using locals. It seems to be waiting for the promise to resolve and then passes the result rather than the promise. I want to handle the promise (`.then`) in the controller. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: What's an `$mdDialog`?

Comment: @DanielB `$mdDialog` is a service by Angular Material. Look at this Doc https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog.

Comment: @mysticalstick Could you please post a short source code of your example?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up injecting a local that was a function to return the promise.

```
IDialogOptions
...
,locals:{getPromise:()=>thePromise}
```

On the controller side

```
getPromise().then(()=>some stuff);
```